# Customize the message in Android inApp purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am implementing inApp purchase in my application. I have to change to message that comes while purchasing. And also have to change the purchase button caption.

```
"Please tap 'Continue' to add a payment method an complete your purchase"

to

"My customized message"
```

Is this possible or we can't customize these message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payment process and method is generally controlled by the e-commerce plugin. Think about it, if it gave you control, you (or I) could hack into making the customer believe something else. Its not in the interest of the customer.

If you want to say something, say it before the customer makes the purchase decision. Not during. Hope thats acceptable answer.